# Extraction of values from XML

Tags: xslt, transformation

I have an xml as below

```
<run>
<line number="1">Info.txt</line>
<line number="2">WR_1.txt</line>
<line number="3">WR_2.txt</line>
<line number="4">WR_3.txt</line>
<line number="5">list.txt</line>
<line number="6">filelist.txt</line>
</run>
```

I want to extract all the values except filelist.txt of the above xml in to an another xml. The only thing is - the position of filelist.txt may keep on changing, it may be on the line number 1 or 2 and I want the xslt to ensure that it should always take the other values and not filelist.txt.

Required outout

```
<run>
<line number="1">Info.txt</line>
<line number="2">WR_1.txt</line>
<line number="3">WR_2.txt</line>
<line number="4">WR_3.txt</line>
<line number="5">list.txt</line>
</run>
```

Requesting help from the experts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="run">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="line[not(. = 'filelist.txt')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you @wasmachien How do I renumber the output - like the line number should start from 1